# Integral of a modified bessel of second kind with sqrt

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions

I need to integrate:

$$\int_p^{\infty} x\sqrt{x^2+a}K_0(bx)dx$$

but I can't do it. Following Gradshteyn and Ryzhik 7th Edition, formula 6.565.7 I can resolve it from 0 to infinity but not from p to infinity. I have tried to take off to 6.565.7 the same but between 0 and p but neither I know how to solve it. Any ideas for an exact result or an approximation?

Comment: Computing the integral from $p$ to $\infty$ for general $p$ is the same as finding an antiderivative for $x\sqrt{x^2+a}K_0(bx)$.  So: can you do this special case: $\int \!x\sqrt {{x}^{2}+1}{{\rm K}_0\left(x\right)}{dx}$

Comment: In fact, I was trying  with a=1 doing a variable change but I can't. Sorry but I don't see the antiderivative of this.